# Issue correctly calculating time remaining on file copy

Tags: vb.net

I am having issue correctly estimating a realistic 'time remaining' app for a copy app. I am using a `Filestream` for the copy as the files being copied vary from >1MB to 4GB. I am using `percentageTotal` here to calculate the current position of the filecopy over all:

```
  'Loop through each file in the SourceDir
            For Each ChildFile In SourceDir.GetFiles()

                If (worker.CancellationPending = True) Then
                    e.Cancel = True
                End If

                'Calculate data being moved for eta to completion
                Dim filetotalbytes As Double = ChildFile.Length
                filetotalsofarcopied = filetotalbytes + filetotalsofarcopied


                'Display file being copied
                SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(Me.lblStatus, "Copying: " & line & "\" & ChildFile.Name & "")

                'Do the copy
                ChildFile.CopyTo(Path.Combine(DestDir.FullName, ChildFile.Name), True)

                'Contruct Destination and Source Strings
                deststring = DestDir.ToString & "\" & ChildFile.Name
                Dim sourcedirstring As String
                sourcedirstring = SourceDir.ToString & "\" & ChildFile.Name

        Dim CopyStream As New FileStream(sourcedirstring, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read)
        Dim NewStream As New FileStream(deststring, FileMode.Append)

        Dim Buffer(4096) As Byte
        Dim BytesRead As Integer
        Dim len As Long = CopyStream.Length - 1

        While CopyStream.Position < len


            BytesRead = CopyStream.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)
            NewStream.Write(Buffer, 0, BytesRead)

            percentageTotal = ((NewStream.Length + filetotalsofarcopied) / Overallsize * 100)
            percentageTotal = Decimal.Round(percentageTotal)

            '  SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(Me.lblTotalProgress, "" & percentageTotal & "%")

        End While

        CopyStream.Dispose()
        NewStream.Dispose()
```

I find that the value of `percentageTotal` often jumps rather than increases in a liner fashion as I would expect. Can anyone see where I am going wrong here?

Additionally I cannot perfect the logic of the `secondsremaining` value. It currently shows the copy taking days when initially run before quickly decreasing but obviously not the correct time remaining.

```
 'Start process snippit
 'Start Button Click config - starts the backgroundworker
Public Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

   'Set start value - label22 is hidden on form1
    Label22.Text = "0"

    'Start timers
    Timer3.Start()
    Timer4.Start()


    'Start background worker
    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerSupportsCancellation = True
    BackgroundWorker1.WorkerReportsProgress = True
    BackgroundWorker1.RunWorkerAsync()

End Sub
```

**UPDATED!** And the Timer.Tick code at the end of the form calculating the time remaining:

```
 Private Sub Timer1_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer1.Tick
    byteslastsecond = filetotalsofarcopied
End Sub


'Every tick of Timer4 calculates the time needed to complete the copy.
   Private Sub Timer4_Tick(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Timer4.Tick
    Dim time As Long = Label22.Text
    If percentageTotal = 0 Then
        SetLabelText_ThreadSafe(Me.lblEstTimeLeft, "Estimated Time Left (All Files): Estimating...")
    Else
         Dim secondsRemaining As Double = (Overallsize - filetotalsofarcopied) / (filetotalsofarcopied - byteslastsecond)
        Dim ts As TimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsRemaining)
```

Can anyone correct my logic for the time remaining to be more realistic?

Comment: I would start by turning on Option Strict

Comment: **First**, the `filetotalsofarcopied` variable seems to not be updated. This could be the issue that makes your percentage "jumpy". Just removing it should work. **--- Secondly**, a `Windows.Forms.Timer` already runs on the UI thread, so no need for the `SetLabelText_ThreadSafe()` method unless you use another timer. **--- Thirdly**, the time left of the copy can be calculated like this: `Seconds left = ((Total file size - bytes copied) / (bytes copied - bytes copied last second))`.

Comment: @VisualVincent thanks for the reply - I have updated the code to include where `filetotalsofarcopied` is being updated. How would you write in code your `seconds left =...` ? I am unsure how to express `bytes copied last second`

`secondsRemaining As Double = (Overallsize - filetotalsofarcopied) / (tiletotalsofarcopied - ???)`

Comment: You would have to store a variable that you update in the end of a timer with Interval `1000`. This makes you update the variable each second with how many bytes have been copied so far. Then before that code you can put your _"seconds left"_ calculation, where `???` is the variable you update at the end of the timer.

Comment: The code will then be executed in this order: **(1 second)** -> `Secs left calculation` -> `Update bytes since last sec`.

Comment: And now I also see that the updating of the `filetotalsofarcopied` variable should probably be moved **after** the actual copy process.

Comment: @VisualVincent thats so much for your help! I have updated the Timer.Tick code as you suggested and it works much better. In test I notice that it's still a little off, especially for large date. In the middle of a 1.8GB copy, at 50% the timer reached 0 secs - yet took about another 15 to complete. Is this simply unavoidable with my current code?

Comment: Size doesn't matter (I've used the algorithm myself in a file transfer application), I'll see if there's a problem.

Comment: What's the interval of `Timer1` and `Timer4`?

Comment: `Timer1` is 1000 and `Timer4` is 100

Comment: I edited my answer for another code fix, please see. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem with your code is that you increment `filetotalsofarcopied` by the entire file size even though the entire file isn't copied yet. You should increment it as you copy a block of data.

So remove this:

```
'Calculate data being moved for eta to completion
Dim filetotalbytes As Double = ChildFile.Length
filetotalsofarcopied = filetotalbytes + filetotalsofarcopied
```

and put it in your `While`-loop instead:

```
BytesRead = CopyStream.Read(Buffer, 0, Buffer.Length)
NewStream.Write(Buffer, 0, BytesRead)

filetotalsofarcopied += BytesRead

percentageTotal = ((NewStream.Length + filetotalsofarcopied) / Overallsize * 100)
percentageTotal = Decimal.Round(percentageTotal)
```

This should make both the time estimation work correctly, and the percentage display.

---

**You should also remove this:**

```
'Do the copy
ChildFile.CopyTo(Path.Combine(DestDir.FullName, ChildFile.Name), True)
```

because you're wasting both time and resources by copying the file twice.

---

**EDIT:**

Actually, I made a mistake by missing something.

This:

```
percentageTotal = ((NewStream.Length + filetotalsofarcopied) / Overallsize * 100)
```

should be this:

```
percentageTotal = (filetotalsofarcopied / Overallsize * 100)
```

since the current amount of written bytes are already added to `filetotalsofarcopied` via the `BytesRead` variable.

Comment: @visualvincet I updated my code to reflect your changes and it works much better! Thank you again so much for your help!

Comment: @Adam : No problem, I'm glad to help! But with "better" do you mean it works as you want, or just better than before but not fully as you want?

Comment: @visialvincent It is better than before for sure, but the time remaining correlation between the %complete and the time remaining counting down to zero is still off a little - especially with large volumes of small files (ca~8MB). I put it down the "Windows time". How could it be better? You've already helped so much I can't ask for more...

Comment: @Adam : Of course you can ask for more, I'm glad to help :). Though I have a little hard time understanding what you mean... Did you try my edit? I feel it's a bit difficult continuing this conversation via comments though, so if you want you can send me an e-mail. Just go to my website via my Stack Overflow profile and then to the "Support" section. You'll find the e-mail address in there (there's only one). If you don't want to send an e-mail that's fine, and we'll continue this in comments. :)

Comment: @Adam : And you're in a bit of luck because I am currently working on a file shredder application, which includes writing large amounts of data and reporting it's exact progress. So this progress calculation thing is currently a hot topic for me, so fixing your code shouldn't be all too hard :). Today I actually successfully managed to properly report the overall progress for all files being shredded.